# Blur.JS not working with Amazon S3 Images

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, cors

I'm using Blur.js (http://blurjs.com/) to blur images within my Rails app. I recently started storing images with Amazon S3 instead of in the filesystem. Now, when blur.js tries to blur the image, I get this error in the Chrome Console:

```
Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
Uncaught Error: unable to access image data: Error: unable to access local image data: ReferenceError: netscape is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

We have a bug in blur.js. When drawing the image to canvas and get the image binary data from the canvas, you need to ensure the source image has a special attribute that allows CORS operation.

In blur.js,

```
tempImg = new Image();
if(formattedSource.match(/http:\/\/|https:\/\//)){
    tempImg.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable **[CORS](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html)** for your S3 bucket containing the images you wish to manipulate via Javascript. From the above docs

> Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) defines a way for client web applications that are loaded in one domain to interact with resources in a different domain. With CORS support in Amazon S3, you can build rich client-side web applications with Amazon S3 and selectively allow cross-origin access to your Amazon S3 resources.

By setting up resource sharing between your S3 bucket and your domain (where Blur.js is being used),the warning/error mentioned in your question should go away.

Comment: I edited the CORS on my bucket with the following and it still doesn't work:

`<CORSConfiguration>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>http://www.mydomain.com</AllowedOrigin>

   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>

   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
 </CORSRule>
 <CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>`

Comment: Is there a solution? Am I not granting access with the right permissions?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert on Amazon's CORS or your setup. My answer is merely letting you know *why* you're getting the error you are and bumping you in the right direction to fix it.